# The Most Wonderous Hall of Hats

Tags: feature-request, archive, winter-bash

How about we create some pages of past leaderboards for the Winterbash Hat event?

It would be a permanent archive so we could always view the past stats for Winterbash (since it now seems like it will be an ongoing event).  It would be good for posterity and the history of the community, and give a little more "permanent" incentive for chasing hats.

Answer (score 6):

While the leaderboard link does not work, I would like to point out that the site http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/ is still accessible, and that if you log-in the system still shows your obtained hat.

<strike>Since the data for your hat is still there, I would think that making the leaderboard work again would be doable (even if not cost free, we should evaluate the cost it would need and the load it could cause)</strike>

Update: the leaderboards are indeed still there, but the main link doesn't work, so you will have to jump to the appropriate sublink for the specific site. For example:

http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/stackoverflow.com

http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/sharepoint.stackexchange.com

also notice that the meta site switch has broken the old meta stackoverflow leaderboard. It still somehow work but search or personal stats are somehow borked.

http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/meta.stackoverflow.com/

Also notice that pagination in the leaderboard seems to be misbehaving, so I would suspect that the sites are still there because they never took them down, not because they officially wanted to keep them. Older site for 2012 seem to be gone (used to be http://winterba.sh/ , now points to a page with some screens).

I conclude that the sites begin still online isn't something the staff really planned, so we should assume they could be taken down every moment. I won't be surprised if when the 2014 bash site comes up, the old one goes down forever. After all, it was intended to be archived: [link here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214927/will-winter-bash-page-stick-around).

> [image]

In the original intent of the question, I would say that we need an official statement from the staff. If an archive is to be done, it should be something they actually planned, not an half working forgot copy as the current one seems to be ^_^.

---

**UPDATE**: as of 4/12/2014, the old site was archived, so now all of the above info is obsolete. The url now redirects to:

https://stackexchange.com/promos/14/winter-bash-2013

and just displays some images of the old site.

Answer (score 1):

Yay, hatz!

There are leaderboards for the winterbach-2013, for example:

- [Stack Overflow](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/stackoverflow.com)
- [Super User](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/superuser.com)
- [Server Fault](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/serverfault.com)

and so on!

Comment: Isn't this exactly what SPArchaeologist said in [their answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243966/162704) an hour ago?

Comment: @Yannis Wait... No. I missed it, but actually he says that "leaderboard does not work"...

Comment: and the link doesn't. Only direct link works.

Comment: @Spa yeah, it doesn't... but... go further :)

Comment: Ah, I see, the leaderboard works only if you specify the site. Regardless, we have no idea of knowing if this will work in the future.

Comment: @Yan But also we don't know if SE will work tomorrow... or do we? :D

Comment: @Yannis still, seems that the pages working may not be intended. See my reply, some functionalities don't seem to work

Comment: Yeah, I think SE just didn't bother to take them off @SPArchaeologist.

Comment: @Yannis, I think I have found something official, please have a look at my answer.