# Preserve the hats - let us have screenshots of all hats and their description

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013

Following [this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214423/the-most-wonderous-hall-of-hats) which is about stats, my mission is more simple and doable by us, ordinary users.

Let's archive all hats and their descriptions as they appear in the [official page](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/) which won't survive long.

I will put here all hats I can see "open", please anyone who see hat that is not listed, add it as well.

### Ordinary hats

1. R-E-S-P-E-C-T
   [image]
2. Sock Puppet
   [image: Sock Puppet]
3. L'chaim
   [image: L'chaim]
4. Ho Ho Ho
   [image: Ho Ho Ho]
5. Do the Swim!
   [image: Do the Swim!]
6. Upboated
   [image: Upboated]
7. Mr. Binx
   [image: Mr. Binx]
8. Full House
   [image: Full House]
9. Lonesome Cowboy
   [image: Lonesome Cowboy]
10. Hi Ho Silver
    [image: Hi Ho Silver]
11. Mr. Peanut Monopoly McDuck
    [image: Mr. Peanut Monopoly McDuck]
12. The Milliner
    [image: The Milliner]
13. Make It Rain
    [image: Make It Rain]
14. Marauder
    [image]
15. Passed Judgement
    [image: Passed Judgement]
16. Reanimated
    [image: Reanimated]
17. Peanut Gallery
    [image]
18. Oh the Horror
    [image]
19. “First!”
    [image: First!]
20. Winter Is Coming
    [image: Winter Is Coming]
21. Chatty Chatty
    [image: Chatty Chatty]
22. Florence Nightingale
    [image: Florence Nightingale]
23. A Link to the Past
    [image: A Link to the Past]
24. Old Hat
    [image: Old Hat]
25. Archaeologist
    [image: Archaeologist]
26. Hello, World!
    [image: Hello, World!]
27. Boater
    [image: Boater]
28. Defender of the Realm
    [image: Defender of the Realm]
29. Conspiracy Theorist
    [image: Conspiracy Theorist]
30. Frosty the Snowman
    [image: Frosty the Snowman]
31. UpDo
    [image: UpDo]
32. Bounty Hunter
    [image: Bounty Hunter]
33. The Stallman
    [image: The Stallman]
34. Robocop
    [image: Robocop]
35. The Question
    [image]

### Secret hats (display only, no spoilers about how to get them)

1. Johnny Three-hats
   [image: Johnny Three-hats]
2. Ghost of Winterbash Past
   [image: Ghost of Winterbash Past]
3. Chuck Yeager
   [image: Chuck Yeager]
4. I'm Not Listening
   [image: I'm Not Listening]
5. I See Your Point
   [image: I See Your Point]
6. Eureka!
   [image: Eureka!]
7. Before It Was Cool
   [image]
8. IG-88
   [image]
9. With Great Power…
   [image]
10. Don Draper
    [image]

Comment: Taking it from a users profile gives bigger images of the hats and you can pick them from others. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters#winter-bash). But those don't have the green background.

Comment: @juergend yep, I prefer those kind, if I'll see nobody adding when winterbash is nearly over I will revert to the option of taking from other users profile pages.

Comment: @ProgramFOX thanks! Note the image descriptions you added are "alt" text meaning displayed only when the image is broken. Did you mean to add it as tooltip?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Yes, I thought that the "image description" would create a tool tip.

Comment: @ProgramFOX cheers, see my edit now (click "side-by-side markdown") to learn how to add tooltip. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Nice, thanks!

Comment: @Laura thanks! That's one secret hat... must admit I suspected there will be hat for posting popular ad following Tim Post (or was it shog?) hint "words that stir and move and sing" long before the hat was uncovered but checking the [profile of a user who posted a very popular ad](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/246053/eisenbergeffect) I saw no hat so ditched the idea. How come he did not earn the hat??

Answer (score 6):

If you want higher resolution ones, here are all the hats that show on my Winter Bash page **at 128px resolution** (including HiDPI text), and [here's the sprite](http://cdn-prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash2013/img/sprite-128.png).

[image: R-E-S-P-E-C-T to Passed Judgement]
[image: Reanimated to Frosty the Snowman]
[image: Updo and some secret hats]

Comment: Thanks, I considered using just a single screenshot, but having a list is more useful in my opinion.