# Using a winter event hat on our GD.SE GameJam logo

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013, legal, licensing

Last autumn we held a GameJam over at gamedev.se ([The Fall 2013 GDSE Game Jam](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1356/the-first-gdse-gamejam)) and now we're preparing for the winter jam. The existing logo doesn't exactly spell out "winter" though, and some customization might be appropriate.

[image]

One idea was to take one (or three?) of the hats that were used during the winter event here, and place it (them?) on our logo. Not sure if this would be okay with the big bosses™ though, and there is no way for us to get the hats now that they've been removed from the site.

Hence this question. Is there something we can do to get hats on our logo?

Comment: Screenshots of all the hats can be found here; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214528/preserve-the-hats-let-us-have-screenshots-of-all-hats-and-their-description. As to who will be angry if you use them; I'll leave that to the big bosses to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no problem with this. You can find [screenshots of all the hats here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214528/preserve-the-hats-let-us-have-screenshots-of-all-hats-and-their-description/214532#214532), including a link to [the sprite sheet](http://cdn-prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash2013/img/sprite-128.png) (which also includes some "troll hats" - red herring hats that weren't actually earnable).

If you use any of these hats in your game jam logo, we just ask that you credit the designer who created this year's batch of hats, [Elias Stein](http://eliasstein.com/), in your blog or meta post (or wherever else you are announcing this).

Comment: Why couldn't we actually get the Twilight Sparkle hat?! :O