# Will Winter Bash page stick around?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013

Now hats are gone for the year, I was wondering if the winter bash page will stick around?
http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/

The reason I ask is, I found a critical bug in Firefox nightly, that shows up on that page:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=953074

It won't be useful for debugging if it goes 404 pretty soon.

Comment: The site did not stick around last year. For the FF bug, I'd isolate the problem into a SSCCE and not rely on an external site, however stable the site might appear. The bug report being stable long-term is valuable too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's what I was thinking, but oddly enough, File->Save-web-page-complete doesn't save the page fully with its javascript, even the Scrapbook addon won't save it. (Saved page has no snow effect.) Does it have some sort of DRM that won't run the script except on that domain?

Comment: JavaScript scripts do not support DRM. More likely that the webpage save functionality missed something requiring rewriting, or perhaps an AJAX call is used that now fails.

Comment: Javascript certainly could have "DRM", packing or minifying, or checking location.href to make sure it only runs on a certain domain. Looks like that bug no longer happens in Nightly though.

Answer (score 2):

The mini-site for Winter Bash will stick around for a short period of time (days, not weeks), then we'll archive it and redirect that site to our [Community Promotions Archive](https://stackexchange.com/promos), which will contain only screenshots and brief descriptions.

Comment: Six to eight days, I'm sure.